# Software Update Center gone grey

Tags: software-center, screen

My SUC is grey, I see nothing but a grey screen.

```
lsb_release -rd
Description:    Ubuntu 11.04
Release:    11.04
```

sudo apt-cache policy software-center

```
software-center:
  Installed: 4.0.4
  Candidate: 4.0.4
  Version table:
 *** 4.0.4 0
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.0 0
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main i386 Packages
```

I have tried this:

```
sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install software-center sudo apt-get clean
```

[image: grey background]

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?  That happened to me and a reboot fixed it.

Comment: Try to run it from the console, the command is software-centre, it could show some valuable info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rebooted my system and the problem was resolved.